# General solution of $\tan (2x)\tan (x)=1$

Tags: trigonometry, proof-writing, proof-explanation

For the question, $\tan (2x) \tan x=1$, I divided it by $\tan x$, and got the solution as $\frac{(2n+1)\pi}{6}$.

$\tan 2x= \cot x= \tan\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-x\right)$. So, $2x=n\pi+ \frac{\pi}{2}-x$. So, $3x= \frac{(2n+1)\pi}{2}$

But the book solved using the formula of $\tan (2x)$, and got the solution as  $\frac{(6n \pm 1)\pi}{6}$. I can see that my solution has odd multiples of $\pi/2$, which should be discarded, but I thought of it only after checking the solution. Also, in a way, it suggests that we can't solve these questions in different ways because that way we might get extra solutions. So, how to ensure which method to follow?

Comment: "but I thought of it only after checking the solution" You should always check whether the solutions you reach actually solve the original equation.

Comment: The usual way. tan2x=cotx=tan(pi/2-x). so, 2x=n.pi+pi/2-x. So, 3x=(2n+1)pi/2.

Comment: Dividing by $\tan x$ assumes $\tan x$ is defined, and going from the equation $\tan(2x)=\tan(\pi/2-x)$ to $2x=n\pi +(\pi/2-x)$ assumes the equation is true when both sides are undefined (which is not the case). You can solve these questions in different ways, it's just that tracking assumption-making and discarding extraneous solutions must be considered as part of the way.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: @runway44- I thought from the given equation, it was clear that tan x is non-zero. So, we could divide by it.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig- Thanks for the link.

Comment: @runway44 - Just reread your comment. Understood your point now. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used a different approach to solve this and tried to keep everything generalized without any predefined assumptions.

$$\tan (2\theta)\tan (\theta)=1  $$

$$ \Longrightarrow \frac{2\tan^2(\theta)}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}  -1 = 0$$

$$ \Longrightarrow \frac{3\tan^2(\theta) -1}{1-\tan^2(\theta)}   = 0$$

Solving for $3\tan^2(\theta) -1 = 0 $ we get $\theta = n\pi  \pm  \frac{\pi}{6}$.

However if $\frac{1}{1-\tan^2(\theta)} = 0 $ then $\tan(\theta)$ must be undefined which surely won't satisfy our original solution.

Thus to conclude the solution is $\theta = n\pi  \pm  \frac{\pi}{6}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your way is better, I think:

The domain gives $\cos2x\neq0$,$\cos{x}\neq0$ and $\sin{x}\neq0$ and by your idea we obtain:
$$\tan2x=\cot{x}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin2x\sin{x}-\cos2x\cos{x}}{\cos2x\sin{x}}=0$$ or
$$\cos3x=0$$ or
$$x=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{\pi}{3}k,$$ where $k\in\mathbb Z$.

Now, delete from these roots, roots of $\sin{x}=0$ (which is impossible), $\cos2x=0$ (which is impossible again) and $\cos{x}=0.$

We can get an answer by the following way.

From $\cos3x=0$ on the interval $(0,2\pi)$ we got the following numbers:
$$\left\{\frac{\pi}{6},\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{5\pi}{6},\frac{7\pi}{6},\frac{3\pi}{2},\frac{11\pi}{6}\right\}.$$

$\frac{\pi}{2}$ and $\frac{3\pi}{2}$ we need to delete and since
$$\frac{11\pi}{6}=\pi+\frac{5\pi}{6}$$ and
$$\frac{7\pi}{6}=\pi+\frac{\pi}{6},$$ we got the following series:
$$x=\frac{\pi}{6}+\pi k$$ and
$$x=\frac{5\pi}{6}+\pi k$$ or $$\left\{\frac{(\pm1+6)\pi}{6}|k\in\mathbb Z\right\}$$

Comment: The initial equation doesn't require eliminating the solutions with $\sin x=0$ (there are none, though).

Comment: @Bernard See please better the starting post. After dividing of the both sides by $\tan{x}$ we obtain $\cot{x}$ and $\sin{x}\neq0$.

Comment: Yes, but this transformation is not necessary to obtain $\cos 3x=0$.

Comment: @Bernard I tried to restore the Ramit's solution. In any case, with $\cos3x$ it seems very smooth, I think.

Comment: Subtracting $(2m+1)pi/4$ from the obtained solution, I get $(2(2k-3m)-1)pi/12$, which is not a very neat presentation. On the other hand, the book's solution gave the answer without having to subtract anything. I have two questions: a) how to obtain a neat solution from our method; b) is there a way we could pick a method in which we don't have to subtract anything from the obtained solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Ramit I added something. See now.

Comment: Very nice presentation. Thanks.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 1):

$$\tan 2x \tan x=1.~~~(1)$$ $$\Rightarrow \tan 2x = \cot x ~\mbox{if} \tan x \ne 0, \pi/2~~~(2)$$ Therefore, $x \ne k \pi~~~(3)$ and $x \ne (m+1/2)\pi~~~(4).$ 
From (2), we get $$\tan 2x= \cot x= \tan(\pi/2-x) \Rightarrow 2x =\frac{\pi}{2}-x+n\pi\Rightarrow x= \frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{n\pi}{3}.~~~~(3)$$ These solutions cannot satisfy (3) but they do satisfy (4) when $n=3m+1$ So the complete solution of (1) is given by $$x=\frac{\pi}{6}+\frac{n\pi}{3}, n \in I ~\mbox{but}~ n \ne 3m+1, ~\mbox{where}~ m \in I$$

Comment: Can you please elaborate how we got 3m+1?

Comment: @Ramit After getting $\pi/6+n\pi/3$ set it $\ne (m+1/2)\pi$, you get $n \ne 3m+1$Similarly one should  also set it equal to $k\pi$ but then one gets a condition $n=3k-1/2$ which anyway cannot be satisfied by two integers. These two things are required to because we are dividing by eq. (1)  $\tanx$ so it should not be zero or infinity.

Answer (score 1):

Writing the equation as 
$$1=\tan 2x\tan x=\frac{\sin 2x\sin x}{\cos 2x\cos x}\iff\cos 2x\cos x-\sin 2x\sin x=\cos 3x =0$$
with a domain of validity defined by the conditions $\cos x,\cos 2x\ne 0$, i.e.
$$x\not\equiv \tfrac\pi2 \mod\pi,\quad x\not\equiv \tfrac\pi 4\mod\tfrac\pi 2,$$
we obtain at once the solutions
$$3x\equiv \frac \pi2\mod \pi\iff x\equiv \frac\pi6\mod\frac\pi 3.$$
None of these solutions are congruent to $\frac\pi4\bmod\frac\pi2$, but a part of them are congruent to $\frac\pi2\bmod \pi$. Actually, geometrically the solutions are represented by the vertices of a regular hexagon and the solutions to eliminate are represented by the north and south poles of the trigonometric circle. There remains two series of solutions:
$$x\equiv\pm\frac\pi 6\mod \pi.$$

Comment: You have written 3x not equal to pi/2. I think you don't mean it.

Comment: Oh! yes, of course. Fixed it. Thank you for pointing it!

Comment: I didn't understand how you reached the final solution but perhaps it's because I have no idea of geometrical interpretation.

Comment: You simply have to plot the solutions on the trigonometric circle to obtain the hexagon and remove the north and south poles. There remains 4 vertices, which are symmetric by pairs w.r.t. the centre. Is it clear?

Comment: I see now. In spirit, it is similar to what Michael has done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You got certain solutions, but you must check whether or not the functions that you are dealing with are actually defined at those points. And $\tan x$ doesn't exist when $x$ is of the form $\frac\pi2+k\pi$ ($k\in\mathbb Z$).

Comment: But tanx is non-zero.

Comment: Sorry for the silly answer. What do you think now?

Comment: Thanks, but I was wondering if there is a way which could give us concrete answer without having to counter-check it with the given equation.

Answer (score 0):

By your method,

$$\tan(2x)=\tan\left(\frac\pi2-x\right)\iff 2x=\frac\pi2-x+k\pi\iff x=\frac{1+2k}{6}\pi$$ and every step is justified.

But the domain of the LHS excludes $$x=\frac{1+2k}{2}\pi$$ and these solutions must be rejected.

By the method of the book,

$$\frac{2\tan^2x}{1-\tan^2x}=1$$ then

$$2\tan^2x=1-\tan^2x$$ and $$\tan^2x=\dfrac13$$ is only allowed if $\tan^2x\ne1$ and this must be mentioned in the resolution.

Comment: Hi. I just dropped a comment on  Michael's answer. I have the same query here.

Comment: @Ramit: there is nothing "not neat" here. The coefficients in the numerator are $1,5,7,11,13,17,\cdots$ and they can't be expressed as a pure arithmetic sequence.

Comment: by using the formula of tan2x, we are getting a neat solution.

Comment: @Ramit: not neater, unless you have a special definition of neat.